# groovy markup builder HTTP redirect

Tags: groovy

I am using groovy markup builder and want to create an automatic HTTP redirect if the person lands on the page. I have tried the following and the when I build my war and test it, the page just blinks.

```
meta('HTTP-EQUIV': 'REFRESH', 'content': '0', url: 'http://localhost:8080/test-utility/testcase.groovy?tcId=' +params.tcId)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
meta( 'http-equiv' : 'refresh', 
      content      : "0 ; url=http://localhost:8080/test-utility/testcase.groovy?tcId=${params.tcId}" )
```

The [url is part of the `content`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh#Examples), not a separate attribute